# Chrome or chromium window doesn't appear after opening

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, 17.04

I'm new to ubuntu and I'm getting very frustrated so far. I'm trying to get chrome to work properly, as I have a chromecast I would like to use, as well as all the extensions I have on chrome.

I've tried to install it any way possible and tried to install chromium as well. Every time I install it, it shows that it's opened but I cannot see the window. I've tried reinstalling chrome, chromium and ubuntu several times without any luck.

I haven't found a solution online and if I can't find one soon, I'll probably just go back to windows.

I'm running ubuntu 17.04

**what I've tried so far?**

```
google-chrome
```

shows no output but puts an icon in the launcher, but chrome window doesn't appear. same is with chromium

I think it may be a permissions issue. Nothing is being written to .config folder. Checked hidden files and no folders for chrome or chromium. Any ideas on what is causing this?

Comment: how did you try to install it? if you add little bit more details, we'll be more than happy to help you

Comment: I tried installing deb file from their website. I also tried to install it through the terminal. I installed chromium through software center

Comment: and can you update your question with the output of `google-chrome` ?

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: `google-chrome` this is the command used to launch Google chrome browser using CLI (command line interface) all you have to do is open up your terminal and paste `google-chrome` and post the output that you get here

Comment: Nothing shows in the terminal. After typing google-chrome , the application opens but the window does not open. It shows on the left panel that it's open but I can't see anything

Comment: Same thing happens with chromium

Comment: what's the output of `ps -ef` , this command shows running processes run this command after opening chrome, update your question with the output (don't post it in comment)

Answer (score 11):

Let try this..
Go to system setting -> Select display setting
Check whether how many displays are enabled. If enabled more than one
then turn off the unused display or enable mirror option.
This can solve your issue.

Comment: This **might** work, but would be better off as a comment asking the OP if he is using Ann external display.

Comment: Actually this answer worked for me even though I am not using an external display. I am running ubuntu 16 on a macbook pro and enabling mirroring forced the invisible chrome windows to re-appear.

Comment: This does not work.

Comment: Awesome. This solved it for me!

Comment: This worked for me. I actually have two monitors, but the second was not powered on. After I powered on the second monitor the Chrome browser was there. This might sound logical, but as I usually need the second monitor only for one specific application, I never expected Chrome to be there.

Comment: i feel so PEBKAC right now.

Comment: I have an external monitor and in settings it says i have three monitors. I turned of mirror and there were still two monitors available. I turned off the second monitor that is non existent and chrome started to appear.

Answer (score 1):

Try opening Chrome with the `--no-sandbox` switch.

I managed to get Chrome 59 running using that switch, but since it's deprecated it pops up a warning. I've rolled back to Chrome 58 for now.

Answer (score -1):

First get a terminal and type 
sudo install gdebi
Enter your password and type "y" when prompted
Run Firefox and google "chrome"
Save "deb 64"
Open using gdebi
It will work perfectly

Comment: Already tried that. Did not work. Seems as though chrome opens, I just can't view the window