# Chromium and Chrome are invisible on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, lts

Opening Chromium or Chrome doesn't show the navigation window.

How to solve this issue, please?

Comment: Maybe this will be helpul https://askubuntu.com/questions/108287/chrome-or-chromium-icon-doesnt-show-in-the-launcher?rq=1

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, it not helped.

Comment: After reading the post below, I changed the monitor settings to single screen so Chromium and Google Chrome are working fine now.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/911899/chrome-or-chromium-window-doesnt-appear-after-opening?rq=1

Comment: @Muzaffar the question you link to is about not showing the launcher. You may therefore want to retract your close vote.